# Test REST WCF Endpoints

Tags: wcf

This is a different question than my previous post on testing WCF.

This time after I've created my service, I want to test it not via WSDL, but I want to send an ajax request using $.ajax via jQuery.

I'm not sure how to wire up the service so that it's ready to recieve requests.  Do I need the service setup and running in IIS?  Or is there a way I can run the WCF project to run the service and then somehow in my NUnit Unit test create the jquery to make an HttpRequest..meaning would it know that the service is up and running?  how?

Comment: look at this http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2008/12/11/testing-wcf-rest-services.aspx. Also you can use Fiddler.

Comment: If you are hosting your service on IIS then you can directly run your test case that would send a request to the service on IIS. If either self hosting or hosted as windows service then you need to start them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can host your service in the IIS, As a windows service or in a console app. To me it sounds wrong to call the service in a Unit test. Normally you mock out all external dependencies in a Unit test.

Comment: good point yes we should be mocking.  I will change that later.